# DOM manipulation inside SimpleModal box

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-plugins, simplemodal

I'm having issues trying to append dynamically created html inside a SimpleModal box (OSX style).

```
<div id="osx-modal-content">
    <div id="osx-modal-title">Foo Modal</div>
    <div class="close"><a href="#" class="simplemodal-close">x</a></div>
        <div id="osx-modal-data">
        <a class="dynamic">Click</a>
        <span class="for-dynamic-link"></span>
        <p><button class="simplemodal-close">Close</button> <span>(or press ESC or click the overlay)</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

After closing the modal box all dynamically inserted html disappears.
Is there something in the plugin that i can tweak to fix this?

```
$("#osx-modal-data").find("a.dynamic").bind("click", function() {
    $("#osx-modal-data span.for-dynamic-link").append("<p>Foo Test</p>");
    return false;
});
```

My main problem is that i can't use [AutoSuggest Jquery Plugin](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin) because everytime i close and re-open the modal box it shows a pretty bad buggy behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the persist:true option. You can either modify the source or after SimpleModal is loaded and before the osx JS is run, add:

```
<script>
    $.modal.defaults.persist = true;
</script>
```

If that doesn't work, let me know.